# How to correctly set androidTheme in cordova-plugin-datepicker plugin

Tags: android, cordova, datepicker, ionic-framework, ionic2

I can't get any of the setting options for [androidTheme](https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker#androidtheme---android) to work for the DatePicker plugin for Ionic/Cordova listed in http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/DatePicker/

The value options read:

> Values: THEME_TRADITIONAL | THEME_HOLO_DARK | THEME_HOLO_LIGHT |
>   THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK | THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT

But, for example,

```
options = {
  date: new Date(),
  mode: 'date',
  androidTheme: 'THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT'
}
```

does nothing to change the theme option. No matter what I try, I still get this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs are a little confusing since the values listed in the docs are strings, but [androidTheme actually takes an int](https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker#androidtheme---android).

> Choose the theme of the picker
>
> ***Type: Int***
>
> Values: THEME_TRADITIONAL | THEME_HOLO_DARK | THEME_HOLO_LIGHT | THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK | THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT
>
> Default: THEME_TRADITIONAL

Practically, the values map to:

```
THEME_TRADITIONAL = 1
THEME_HOLO_DARK = 2
THEME_HOLO_LIGHT = 3
THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK = 4
THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT = 5
```

So, depending on your androidTheme, your var option would read:

```
options = {
  date: new Date(),
  mode: 'date',
  androidTheme: 5, // because THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT = 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
options = {
  date: new Date(),
  mode: 'date',
  androidTheme: datePicker.ANDROID_THEMES.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT
}
```

Worked for me :)